# Auto fill in fields in WebView android 

Tags: javascript, android, webview, field

i want to fill in fields with this code but it gives me error

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
      // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat
      // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type values.


      String possibleEmail = account.name;



    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    setTitleColor(Color.GRAY); //the title bar color
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.gmail.com");
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('id_email').value ='"+possibleEmail+"'};");


}
```

It gives me this error

05-02 20:28:24.191: E/Web Console(1402): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at :1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

loadURL is asynchronous; in other words, calling loadUrl kicks off the HTTP request, but then returns immediately, before the document is downloaded and rendered.  The error you're seeing is because you're trying to execute the javascript too early (before the document is downloaded, parsed, and rendered).

You'll need to use a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished), and wait for the page to finish loading before you execute your javascript.  Try the onPageFinished callback, but be careful that you can sometimes get multiple callbacks because of iFrames and the like.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**
If you are targeting KITKAT and above then you also have to take care of which method to use based on android version. Follwoing code give a much better explanation:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
 {
        webView.evaluateJavascript(yourScript, null);
 }
 else
 {
       webView.loadUrl(yourScript);

 }
```

Comment: hey . can you please refer to any full example. I have not worked with this kind of code before .